# How to plot the later movement of a fluid flux following an angular displacement as a parabolic figure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If I have a flux of water being ejected by a hose at 10 m/s, which is then gradually moved sideways at an angular velocity of 40 °/s, the trajectory of the flux as seen from above can be described as a parable. However, knowing both the linear velocity of the flux and angular velocity of the source being displaced sideways, how can I calculate the curvature of the parable?

Comment: Based on your description you should have a circular uniform movement. Why you say that it is a parable?

Comment: Maybe a parable is not the correct figure, but I can’t see an uniformly circular movement being the best description of the profile of a water flux seen from above, if the source is moving sideways - but perhaps I’m wrong.

Comment: But the angular speed is constant, there's an ucm. And it is respect of the end of the hose? Respect of what is given the angular speed?

Comment: Yes, the angular velocity is in respect to the end of the water hose.

Comment: Why you think it isn't an ucm?